# chef won't start my init.d service

Tags: mongodb, centos, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm creating a service via this [mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/).

I have this in my recipe to install the service via a template:

```
service 'disable-transparent-hugepages' do
  supports :restart => true, :start => true, :stop => true, :reload => true
  action :nothing
end

template 'disable-transparent-hugepages' do
  path '/etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepages'
  source 'disable-transparent-hugepages.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  notifies :enable, 'service[disable-transparent-hugepages]'
  notifies :start, 'service[disable-transparent-hugepages]'
end
```

When I run the recipe multiple times it pulls the init.d script to the right location, but if I check the status of it I see this:
[image]

After I confirmed its installed I added a line in the recipe to just start the service like normal:

```
service 'disable-transparent-hugepages' do
  action :start
end
```

But still it isn't started.

If I manually start it I can see it working:
[image]

Why isn't chef starting the service?

Edit: Ok so I found [this SO question](https://serverfault.com/questions/495969/service-doesnt-start-when-using-chef) that says my problem might be that I need the init.d script (found in the link to the mongo doc) needs to exit with a non 0 return code. I am unsure though how to have the script return a non zero code when checking the status.

Comment: Can you share some chef run debug logs when "template" tries to notify the service resource for start.

Comment: Well I don't think that's the problem. Regardless of whether notify is working, it copies the init.d script to the right place and I can see its loaded as per my screen shots. At that point even if I add a line that merely starts the service it doesn't start it. Its not even able to start the service let alone notify so I'd like to get that far first

Comment: If that is the case, you may like to add some echo in the int script to see, if it is being called. Also, echo environment variables in the init script to check, if there is any difference.

Comment: I see that `:start` is supported... is `:enable` supported also?

Comment: If I add :enable to the supports line it still won't start it. I didn't think enable was the problem it won't start the service it only starts if I manually run systemctl start <theservice>

Comment: @vikingsteve `:enable` as nothing to do with the problem, it just ask chef to setup the system to start the service on the defaults runlevel (I.e: calling `update-rc.d` on ubuntu, or `chkconfig` on redhat). This is an action of the chef resource, not a parameter to the init script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the assumption on what the script support as command.

Quoting chef doc about [`service` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html#properties) about the `supports`  property (emphasis on last line is mine):

> `supports` Ruby Type: **Hash**
>
> A list of properties that controls how the chef-client is to attempt
>   to manage a service: :restart, :reload, :status. For :restart, the
>   init script or other service provider can use a restart command; if
>   :restart is not specified, the chef-client attempts to stop and then
>   start a service. For :reload, the init script or other service
>   provider can use a reload command. For :status, the init script or
>   other service provider can use a status command to determine if the
>   service is running; if :status is not specified, the chef-client
>   attempts to match the service_name against the process table as a
>   regular expression, unless a pattern is specified as a parameter
>   property. Default value: { :restart => false, :reload => false,
>   :status => false } for all platforms (**except for the Red Hat platform**
>   **family, which defaults to { :restart => false, :reload => false,**
>   **:status => true }.**)

when `status` is `true`, the provider try to call it, if it returns `0` the service is supposed to be running.

According to the link you gave, the script only support `start` and hence return 0 when called with parameter status.

One way to fix this is using a more precise definition of the service like this:

```
service 'disable-transparent-hugepages' do
  supports :restart => false, :start => true, :stop => false, :reload => false, :status => false
  action :start
end
```

Another way would be to fix the init script to implement the status command, returning 0 if the file have the proper content and 1 if not.

Something along this line as status case would do I think (untested):

```
status)
if [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage ]; then
  thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage
elif [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage ]; then
  thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage
else
  return 0
fi

re='^(0|no)$'
return [[ $(cat ${thp_path}/khugepaged/defrag) =~ $re ]]
;;
```

My opinion:

As it is not exactly a real service, I would go to manage those files directly instead of using a pseudo service for this.

Comment: While I could just do this in chef without it I like the pseudo service because it runs on boot and takes care of redhat 6 and 7- while that logic is pretty trivial it means I don't have to handle it in the recipe.

Comment: In this case I would add a guard (only_if or not_if) testing the content of the files to avoid chef starting the service on each run. The syntax above will work, with status: false chef will check in the process list for something matching the service name, if there's nothing it will consider the service as stopped. (There's another option, I'll edit the post)

Comment: I asked a question about this recently on SO, but if I use the chef-client cookbook to configure it as a service (which I do on all nodes) chef-client should run as soon as the server boots up right? I guess if thats the case then I probably will use chef instead of the service.

Comment: There's the `splay` configuration option witch would come into play for the first run, so maybe no exactly at boot if you don't set it at 0 (which may hang your chef-server if you have multiples machines rebooting together). You can also invoke a chef-client run with crontab with the `@reboot` keyword instead of the timing entries (same warning as above).